# Erro FFmpeg com stream de vídeo

Tags: http, streaming, vídeo

Estou tentando fazer uma stream usando uma webcam como input de dados com FFmpeg, mas preciso que além do stream ele grave um vídeo. As duas funcionalidades com um mesmo comando durante alguns minutos.

(Se colocado separadamente o código da gravação funciona perfeitamente já o do streaming não funciona e apresenta o mesmo erro.)

Fiz o teste com duas versões de código diferentes e obtive o mesmo erro referente a URL de output do streaming.

É importante dizer também que está tudo certo com o servidor.

**Código FFmpeg:**

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2048M -i "video=Integrated Webcam" -t 300 -c:v libx264 
-segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_format mp4 meuvideo.mp4 -f mpegts -q:v 5 -codec:v 
mpeg1video https://urlexemplo.com.br:8081/rota
```

**Log:**

```
    ffmpeg started on 2017-11-20 at 15:52:22
Report written to "ffmpeg-20171120-155222.log"

ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers

built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib

  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100

libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100

Input #0, dshow, from 'video=Integrated Webcam':
  Duration: N/A, start: 9581.085000, bitrate: N/A

Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 10000k tbn, 10000k tbc

https://urlexemplo.com.br:8081/rota: Unknown error
```

(A aplicação está sendo escrita com Node.js e Electron)

Executei o comando -report e gerei um relatório. Não dá pra colar diretamente aqui porque é muito grande, pode ser encontrado no link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ow76gddst98iolt/ffmpeg-20171120-155222.log?dl=0

**Independente de como eu escreva o código do FFmpeg sempre dá erro na url do output.** Existe algum modo específico para se fazer a stream de vídeo com HTTP? Algum comando que esteja faltando e que justifique o erro?

---

**Edit 1:**

Para testar, coloquei o endereço udp://@xxx.x.x.x:1234 (xxx.x.x.x -> IP) no lugar da url e o comando rodou, assisti a streaming com o VLC e ele ainda gravou o vídeo apropriadamente durante os cinco minutos solicitados.

A dúvida continua sendo: **Existe algum parâmetro especial para trabalhar com endereços HTTP?**

Comment: Pelo log não parece haver nada errado com o comando em si... O servidor escutando na porta :3030 é um *relay* ou um *client* direto? Ele está no ar? Você disse que o código da gravação funciona sozinho, o do stream também funciona sozinho?

Comment: SIm, o servidor está no ar e não o código do stream não funciona sozinho ele apresenta o mesmo erro. "Unknown error" na url

Comment: No caso você consegue gravar o que está na webcam, correto? O problema acontece ao inserir o segundo streaming, certo?